# How to schedule a custom field value update?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a boolean checkbox custom field using ACF to mark a post as "featured", so it shows up on the homepage slider.

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a timer so these posts only remain as "featured" for a limited amount of time (say 1 week) by default, this way the writers and editors of the website won't need to do this manually every time.

I have looked into `wp_schedule_event()` at the [WordPress documentation page for the function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) but I don't really have an idea on how to use this in order to implement such functionality. I also haven't found any similar problem being discussed in any forum.

I'm a beginner at WordPress development, so I'm still somewhat lost in this.

Thank you in advance!